# Why array appears as a string, but when I print it to console it print it as an array? ReactJS functional component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a functional component of a card.
inside that card there is an accordion.

accordion: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/accordion/#basic-example

inside of that I want to do a choosing from a dropdown list using the `<select>` and `<option> jsx tags`.
I receive from the data base a `json`. in that `json` there is a `key` that it's `value` is an `array` of `Strings`.

I want to take the array, and for every element in it to do an option for the user to chose.
I used this code that I learnt from a ReactJS crash course (but it doesn't work in my case):

*NOTICE THAT `PROPS.PRODUCT.COLOR`, when I `console.log()` it, is an array. but it doesn't let me use `.map()` on it.

```
<select ref = {myRef}
        required
        className="form-control">


                         {/*  this code is suppose to map the array and for every element in the array
                               to return a new option to the drop down list */}

                                {Array(props.product.color).map(color => {
                                    return <option key={color} value={color} >{color}</option>
                                })}


</select>
```

this code return a "String" and instead of displaying a drop down list, it display only one option, and it all the element combined.

instead of:

1.Green

2.Blue

3.Red
  ...

I get : GreenBlueRed.

my full functional component code:

```
const myRef = createRef()

const FunctionalProductCardComponent = props => (
    // giving the div id only for design pourpse
    <div id="ProductCard">
        <Card style={{ width: '18rem'}}>
        <Card.Img variant="top" src={imageUrl} id='ringImgId'/>
        <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
            <Card.Text>                    
                }
                <tr><td>Name:    {props.product.name}</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Price: {props.product.price}</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Gender:  {props.product.gender}</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Serial:  {props.product.serial}</td></tr>
            </Card.Text>
        </Card.Body>

        {/* this is accordion i took from react-bootstrap
          * for more info about this accordion, please visit: 
          * https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/accordion/ 
          * :) 
          * */}
        {/*to make accordion option open as default: defaultActiveKey="0" */}
        <Accordion>
            <Card>
                <Card.Header>
                <Accordion.Toggle className="accordionToggleButton" as={Button} variant="link" eventKey="0">
                    Size :
                </Accordion.Toggle>
                </Card.Header>
                <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
                <Card.Body>
                    {/* TODO: the option to select from sizes available */}
                </Card.Body>
                </Accordion.Collapse>
            </Card>
            <Card>
                <Card.Header>
                <Accordion.Toggle className="accordionToggleButton" as={Button} variant="link" eventKey="1">
                    Color : 
                </Accordion.Toggle>
                </Card.Header>
                <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="1">
                <Card.Body>
                    <div className='form-group'>
                        <select ref = {myRef}
                                required
                                className="form-control"
                                >
                                {Array(props.product.color).map(color => {
                                    return <option key={color} value={color} >{color}</option>
                                })}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </Card.Body>
                </Accordion.Collapse>
            </Card>
        </Accordion>


    <Card.Body>
        <Card.Link href="#">Buy</Card.Link>
        <Card.Link id="addToCartBtn" href="#">Add To Cart</Card.Link>
    </Card.Body>
    </Card>
</div>
)

export default FunctionalProductCardComponent
```

the component I pass the props to the functional component from:

```
export default class ProductCardComponent extends Component{

constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    // binding the getProductList to 'this' key word so when i call it with 'this' it will know 
    // where to go.
    this.getProductList = this.getProductList.bind(this)

    // the empty list of product
    this.state = {
        product: [],
    }
}


componentDidMount() {
    // axios.get => sending a 'get' http request to the url i passed it.
    axios.get('http://localhost:PORT/table_name/')
    // getting the response, this is 'Promise'
    .then(response => {
        // setting the product list that in the state to be the list of data i got as response
        this.setState({
            product: response.data
        })
    })
    // if there's an error i will catch it here
    // Who you gonna call ??? De-Buggers !!!
    .catch(err => {if (err) console.log(err)})
}

// getting the product list from the state, and turning it into card functional component, so the data 
// is 'drawn' on the cards.
// getting it back from the functional component as an array of ready to display card.
getProductList() {
    // mapping the state (list of products), passing it callback the currentProduct
    return this.state.product.map( currentProduct => {
        // returning new 'FunctionalProductCardComponent' with the data of the current product
        return <FunctionalProductCardComponent product={currentProduct} key={currentProduct._id}/>
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Row>
                {/* calling the method that will create the cards */}
                {this.getProductList()}
            </Row>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Comment: `Array(x)` is not the right way to convert something to a plain array, in case that's what you wanted, instead it's `Array.from(x)`.

Comment: Please check the answer I wrote you, and if it fixed your problem, mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<select ref={myRef} required className='form-control'>    
  {props.product.color.map((color) => {
    return (
      <option key={color} value={color}>
        {color}
      </option>
    );
  })}
</select>;
```

You can execute the .map() function on an any array. What you are doing now is wrapping an array into another array, so instead of having (example data) the following data [1,2,3], you are transforming it into [[1,2,3]]. Because of that, the .map() function is executed just once (because the new array has just ONE element), instead of N times (N = the count of your elements)

Comment: it throws a runtime error:  "props.product.color.map is not a function". I tried it the way you did it yesterday, and that's what I got too. and this is the reason why I wrapped it in Array().

Comment: Add a check if you have data available, because if it is received through an API call, in the initial render it is undefined. Add the following code: { props.product && props.product.color && props.product.color.map()} and then the rest of the code. Let me know the result.

Comment: the same problem. I fixed it as suggested above in the comment of CherryDT with 'Array.from(props.product.color)'. I thought both Array(x) and Array.from(x) give the same result, so I don't really know why it working, but it is. thanks any way :)